# R - lubridate - Convert Period into numeric counting months

Tags: r, lubridate

Consider following:

```
library(lubridate)
period1 = weeks(2)
as.numeric(period1, "weeks")
> 2   # as expected
```

Now I am trying to do similar with months:

```
period2= months(6)
as.numeric(period2, "months")
as.numeric(period2, "weeks")
>  26.08929  # OK
as.numeric(period2,"months")
>  0.04166667  # Not OK?
```

Is this a bug in `lubridate`? Or something wrong I am doing/missing?

Note: I have seen (old) remark [Have lubridate subtraction return only a numeric value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765668/have-lubridate-subtraction-return-only-a-numeric-value), so I guess I may also use workaround to use `difftime` but I would like to stick to lubridate.

Comment: Assuming this is not the desired behavior, I suspect [`seconds_to_unit`](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/blob/c5ddda2aec8dce0c98523817e8d68b8e9d846297/R/coercion.r#L568) or [`period_to_seconds`](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/blob/332cd13828e8e20e409967db25e2f175957ddcef/R/periods.r#L517) might be worth exploring.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of using `as.numeric()` try `time_length()` from lubridate package:

```
period2= months(6)
time_length(period2,unit="days")
#182.6
time_length(period2,unit="weeks")
#26.09
time_length(period2,unit="months")
#6.004
class(time_length(period2,unit="months"))
#"numeric"
```

Comment: Thanks Ishan! I didn't even notice this function in `lubridate` -- so many to know!

Comment: This function is not in the lubridate cheatsheet and also surprised me a lot. 
https://rawgit.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/main/lubridate.pdf