# Given a series of dates and a birth day, is there a way to obtain the age at every date entry along with a final age using the lubridate package?

Tags: r, date, filter, lubridate

I have a database of information pertaining to individuals observed over time. I would like to find a way to obtain the age of these individuals whenever a record was taken. Assuming the BIRTH assigns a value of 0, I would like to obtain the age either in days or months for the visits after. It would also be helpful to obtain a final age (either day or month) for each individual (*not included in the code). For example, for ID (A), the final age would be 10 months. I would like to use the lubridate function as it's in-built date feature makes it easier to work with dates. Any help with this is much appreciated.

```
date<-c("2000-01-01","2000-01-14","2000-01-25","2000-02-12","2000-02-27","2000-06-05","2000-10-30",
        "2001-02-04","2001-06-15","2001-12-26","2002-05-22","2002-06-04",
        "2000-01-08","2000-07-11","2000-08-18","2000-11-27")
ID<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
      "B","B","B","B","B",
      "C","C","C","C")
status<-c("BIRTH","ETC","ETC","ETC","ETC","ETC","ETC",
          "BIRTH","ETC","ETC","ETC","ETC",
          "BIRTH","ETC","ETC","ETC")

df1<-data.frame(date,ID,status)
print(df1)
         date ID status
1  2000-01-01  A  BIRTH
2  2000-01-14  A    ETC
3  2000-01-25  A    ETC
4  2000-02-12  A    ETC
5  2000-02-27  A    ETC
6  2000-06-05  A    ETC
7  2000-10-30  A    ETC
8  2001-02-04  B  BIRTH
9  2001-06-15  B    ETC
10 2001-12-26  B    ETC
11 2002-05-22  B    ETC
12 2002-06-04  B    ETC
13 2000-01-08  C  BIRTH
14 2000-07-11  C    ETC
15 2000-08-18  C    ETC
16 2000-11-27  C    ETC

date.new<-c("2000-01-01","2000-01-14","2000-01-25","2000-02-12","2000-02-27","2000-06-05","2000-10-30",
        "2001-02-04","2001-06-15","2001-12-26","2002-05-22","2001-02-04",
        "2000-01-08","2000-07-11","2000-08-18","2000-11-27")
ID.new<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
      "B","B","B","B","B",
      "C","C","C","C")
status.new<-c("BIRTH","ETC","ETC","ETC","ETC","ETC","ETC",
          "BIRTH","ETC","ETC","ETC","ETC",
          "BIRTH","ETC","ETC","ETC")

age<-c(0,1,1,2,2,6,10,
       0,4,10,15,16,
       0,6,7,10)

df2<-data.frame(date.new,ID.new,status.new,age)

print(df2)
     date.new ID.new status.new age
1  2000-01-01      A      BIRTH   0
2  2000-01-14      A        ETC   1
3  2000-01-25      A        ETC   1
4  2000-02-12      A        ETC   2
5  2000-02-27      A        ETC   2
6  2000-06-05      A        ETC   6
7  2000-10-30      A        ETC  10
8  2001-02-04      B      BIRTH   0
9  2001-06-15      B        ETC   4
10 2001-12-26      B        ETC  10
11 2002-05-22      B        ETC  15
12 2001-02-04      B        ETC  16
13 2000-01-08      C      BIRTH   0
14 2000-07-11      C        ETC   6
15 2000-08-18      C        ETC   7
16 2000-11-27      C        ETC  10
```

Comment: Why is the age for `ID` A on `2000-01-14` 1 and not 0?

Comment: My mistake, should have put 0 instead.

Answer (score 1):

For calculations related to age in years or months, I'd like to encourage you to try the clock package rather than lubridate. lubridate is a great package, but produces some unexpected results with these kinds of calculations if you aren't 100% sure of what you are doing. In clock, the function to do this is `date_count_between()`. Notice that one of the results is different between clock and lubridate here:

```r
library(clock)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- tibble(
  date = c("2000-01-01","2000-01-14",
           "2000-01-25","2000-02-12","2000-02-27","2000-06-05",
           "2000-10-30","2001-02-04","2001-06-15","2001-12-26",
           "2002-05-22","2002-06-04","2000-01-08","2000-07-11",
           "2000-08-18","2000-11-27"),
  ID = c("A","A","A","A","A","A",
         "A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C"),
  status = c("BIRTH","ETC","ETC","ETC",
             "ETC","ETC","ETC","BIRTH","ETC","ETC","ETC","ETC",
             "BIRTH","ETC","ETC","ETC")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = date_parse(date)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(birth_date = date[status == "BIRTH"]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    age_clock = date_count_between(birth_date, date, "month"),
    age_lubridate = as.period(date - birth_date) %/% months(1))
#> # A tibble: 16 × 6
#>    date       ID    status birth_date age_clock age_lubridate
#>    <date>     <chr> <chr>  <date>         <int>         <dbl>
#>  1 2000-01-01 A     BIRTH  2000-01-01         0             0
#>  2 2000-01-14 A     ETC    2000-01-01         0             0
#>  3 2000-01-25 A     ETC    2000-01-01         0             0
#>  4 2000-02-12 A     ETC    2000-01-01         1             1
#>  5 2000-02-27 A     ETC    2000-01-01         1             1
#>  6 2000-06-05 A     ETC    2000-01-01         5             5
#>  7 2000-10-30 A     ETC    2000-01-01         9             9
#>  8 2001-02-04 B     BIRTH  2001-02-04         0             0
#>  9 2001-06-15 B     ETC    2001-02-04         4             4
#> 10 2001-12-26 B     ETC    2001-02-04        10            10
#> 11 2002-05-22 B     ETC    2001-02-04        15            15
#> 12 2002-06-04 B     ETC    2001-02-04        16            15
#> 13 2000-01-08 C     BIRTH  2000-01-08         0             0
#> 14 2000-07-11 C     ETC    2000-01-08         6             6
#> 15 2000-08-18 C     ETC    2000-01-08         7             7
#> 16 2000-11-27 C     ETC    2000-01-08        10            10
```

clock says that `2001-02-04` to `2002-06-04` is 16 months, while the lubridate method here only says it is 15 months. This has to do with the fact that the lubridate calculation uses the length of an *average* month, which doesn't always accurately reflect how we think about months.

Consider this simple example, I think most people would agree that a child born on this date in February is considered "1 month and 1 day" old. But lubridate shows 0 months!

```r
library(clock)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# "1 month and 1 day apart"
feb <- as.Date("2020-02-28")
mar <- as.Date("2020-03-29")

# As expected when thinking about age in months
date_count_between(feb, mar, "month")
#> [1] 1

# Not expected
as.period(mar - feb) %/% months(1)
#> [1] 0

secs_in_day <- 86400
secs_in_month <- as.numeric(months(1))
secs_in_month / secs_in_day
#> [1] 30.4375

# Less than 30.4375 days, so not 1 month
mar - feb
#> Time difference of 30 days
```

The issue is that lubridate uses the length of an average month in the computation, which is `30.4375` days. But there are only 30 days between these two dates, so it isn't considered a full month.

clock, on the other hand, uses the day component of the starting date to determine if a "full month" has passed or not. In other words, because we have passed the 28th of March, clock decides that 1 month has passed, which is consistent with how we generally think about age.

Comment: Today I learned about clock. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate`, we can do the following. We first turn the `date` column into a date. Then we group by `ID`, find the birth date and calculate the number of months since that date via some `lubridate` magic (see [How do I use the lubridate package to calculate the number of months between two date vectors where one of the vectors has NA values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369817/how-do-i-use-the-lubridate-package-to-calculate-the-number-of-months-between-two)).

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(date = as_date(date)) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(birth_date = date[status == "BIRTH"],
         age = as.period(date - birth_date) %/% months(1)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Which gives:

```
   date       ID    status birth_date   age
   <date>     <fct> <fct>  <date>     <dbl>
 1 2000-01-01 A     BIRTH  2000-01-01     0
 2 2000-01-14 A     ETC    2000-01-01     0
 3 2000-01-25 A     ETC    2000-01-01     0
 4 2000-02-12 A     ETC    2000-01-01     1
 5 2000-02-27 A     ETC    2000-01-01     1
 6 2000-06-05 A     ETC    2000-01-01     5
 7 2000-10-30 A     ETC    2000-01-01     9
 8 2001-02-04 B     BIRTH  2001-02-04     0
 9 2001-06-15 B     ETC    2001-02-04     4
10 2001-12-26 B     ETC    2001-02-04    10
11 2002-05-22 B     ETC    2001-02-04    15
12 2002-06-04 B     ETC    2001-02-04    15
13 2000-01-08 C     BIRTH  2000-01-08     0
14 2000-07-11 C     ETC    2000-01-08     6
15 2000-08-18 C     ETC    2000-01-08     7
16 2000-11-27 C     ETC    2000-01-08    10
```

Which is your expected output except for some rounding differences. See my comment on your question.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bas. This has been very helpful